# Main Domain & Subfolders to Main Domain and Subdomains (Search Console)

Tags: google-search-console, search

Hi want to know we launch a new redesign of site (multi regional) we went from one main domain and subfolders to main domain and subdomains,  question is in search console, do I delete the main site sitemap and submit the new one or just submit the new sitemap as the Main domain did not change! i have so many 404's now and i not sure it is because there is 2 sitemaps! Can remove the one and will this help, is google combining the both?I did implement 301s..please help

Answer (score 1):

1. If sitemap contains some URL and it redirect to somewhere else then it will not going to affect at all, so keep your main sitemap as it, it will not going to harmful, may be it will help you to index your new subdomain content faster.
2. Just implement proper 301 redirection, no matter how your sitemap contain any URL's but with proper 301 redirection, google will overwrite it.  so make sure `www.example.com/some/page/` redirect to `some.example.com/page/`. If you implemented proper 301 redirection on every URL then it will never return 404 error page. So please check your 301 redirection again.
3. As I said sitemap does not harm neither it is too useful, it just help Google to discover new content. So when Google see any new URL in sitemap, it will start crawling in their schedule time. So create n number of properties on search console based on n subdomain like `sub.domain.com` and `subn.domain.com` then create individual sitemap for your subdomain, and submit it.
   **Make sure your subdomain sitemap contain only those URL's which is really exist.** I think, here you're doing some mistake. If Google see any URL in your sitemap, and it does not point to any real webpage, then Google will notify you about that 404 URL. So make sure your subdomain sitemap is real, and points to correct URL.

The main thing you should do is proper 301 redirection, if it is good, then you're fine. And check your 404 error, it will also tell you the source from where it is linked.